# How do I merge cell data into a new column?

Tags: google-sheets

```
A | B
-----
1 | a
2 | b
3 | c
```

and I'd like to have a third column that merges the data like this:

```
A |  B  |
---------
1 | 1, a
2 | 2, b
3 | 3, c
```

currently I can kind of do this one row at a time in a column C with this formula:

> = A:A1&", "&B:B1

How can it be done to the entire column B?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it for first row and then drag the formula to next rows in the column.

[image]

Just go to the corner of the cell where you have already applied, the arrow will become a cross hair. Drag it to next rows.

The formula will be automatically updated till the final cell where you drag and values will be calculated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are requesting an array formula:

```
=arrayformula(A1:A&", "&B1:B)
```